# Compiling programme with boost.asio library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, boost-asio

I have installed all boost libraries, but when compiling `g++ sda.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_date_time -lboost_regex -lboost_thread -lboost_serialization`

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

i obtain several errors, and compilation is failed.
i use ubuntu 10.10 up to date.
Compiler says:

```
/tmp/cc6bld0N.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
sda.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
sda.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
sda.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/cc6bld0N.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
sda.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[boost::asio::error::get_system_category()]+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the problem?

Comment: when you say "I have installed all boost libraries" do you mean you installed a compiled version of it or have you built and installed them from source?

Answer (score 1):

Not likely your problem, but you should not need to link against `boost_date_time` or `boost_regex` or `boost_serialization` or `boost_thread`.

```
samm$ cat asio.cc
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
samm$ g++ asio.cc  -I /opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_system -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib
samm$
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Ubuntu have *-dev package for development. Are you sure you've installed libboost-dev instead of libboost ?